# jQuery sort and appendTo not working in Internet Explorer and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, safari

I'm using the jQuery `sort` and `appendTo` functions to reorder a list of span tags based on their content.

It should be pretty easy and is working perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11 and Safari 5 on windows, and I can't find the reason.

The HTML:

```
<div class="ube-all">
   <div class="ube-article">
     <span>bbbb</span>
   </div>
   <div class="ube-article">
     <span>aaaaa</span>
   </div>
   <div class="ube-article">
     <span>ccc</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ube-all .ube-article').sort(function(a,b){
    return $.trim($(a).find('span').eq(0).text())>$.trim($(b).find('span').eq(0).text());
  }).appendTo('.ube-all');
});
```

A jsFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/nxsby7rs/

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array sort method callback function is supposed to return integer that is negative, positive, or `0`, not a boolean value as you will get from your `>` operator.

The correct way to write your sorting function would be compare the strings, and return an integer based on that comparison.

### Working Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ube-all .ube-article').sort(function(a,b){
    var stra = $.trim($(a).find('span').eq(0).text());
    var strb = $.trim($(b).find('span').eq(0).text());
    if (stra < strb) { return -1; }
    if (stra > strb) { return 1; }
    return 0;
  }).appendTo('.ube-all');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ube-all">
   <div class="ube-article">
     <span>bbbb</span>
   </div>
   <div class="ube-article">
     <span>aaaaa</span>
   </div>
   <div class="ube-article">
     <span>ccc</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Since the sorting function expects integers, the real question appear to be:

> Why does this code work at all in some browsers?

Different browsers use different sorting algorithms. It's possible that using some sorting algorithms, it is possible type-cast `true` into positive `1` and `false` into `0` and get a meaningful result. However this is in the land of undefined behavior, and should be avoided.

Comment: Oh! I knew it must be something stupid on my part. I was obfuscated by the fact that it was working in firefox and chrome. Thanks for enlighten me! I will mark the bounty when possible.